# How to read a text file with Node.js and write it to a HTML page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I have a text file that I would like to read with Node.js using the fs module. I know how to read the file but I do not know how to take the data of the text files and be able to put it to a website page.

For Example: I would like to read a file that has the contents of 'hello world!!!' and then using jQuery put it to a div.

Answer (score 5):

**NodeJS is not a web server.**

However, you can easily add dependencies to provide such
capabilities.

e.g. **`express`**, **`koa`**, or **`hapi`**.

So far, you've got [*something like*]:

```
const fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile('data.json', (e, data) => {
    if (e) throw e;
    console.log(data);
});
```

You could use ***`express`*** as follows (*note: if you have not
already run `npm init`, do so and provide sensible defaults*):

```
npm init 
npm install --save express
```

Then, create a file, `app.js`, to serve you're data, e.g.:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use('/', (req, res) => {
    if (e) throw e;

    // **modify your existing code here**
    fs.readFile('data.json', (e, data) => {
        if (e) throw e;
        res.send(data);
    });
});

app.listen(5555);
```

Launch your node "web server":

```
node app.js
```

**Finally**, point your browser to:

```
http://localhost:5555/
```

Comment: I see what you are saying so how would you point it to that because I have my JavaScript files that if a user clicks on a button I want it to make it show the txt file. So how would I do that?

Comment: Please add `const fs = require('fs');`

Answer (score 2):

If you are using jquery and express just build an endpoint on your express server that serves the contents of the text file.

your jquery:

```
$.getJSON("/text", function(data){
   <write code here to render contents of text file to the DOM>
})
```

your end point in node:

```
router.get("/text", function(req, res){
      fs.readFile(textFile, 'utf8', function(err, data) {
        if (err) throw err;
        return res.json(textFile);
      })
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your question you want to "render" the text on the client, not on the server. The easiest way to do this with jQuery is using `$.ajax` like this:

```js
const URL_TO_STATIC_TXT = 'https://cdn.rawgit.com/fabe/2a371ce28effb32fa1120f8d25225d37/raw/6d0bfebff1d0b52d72ed5ded4011a0bbff80d679/file.txt';
  
$.ajax({ url: URL_TO_STATIC_TXT })
  .done(data => {
    $('body').text(data);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Then you only need to host the static `.txt` files with Node.js, without even using `fs`. With Express you can achieve this with `app.use`:

```
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

---

If you want to render the files on the server (using `fs`) you can also look into countless templating libraries like [pug](https://github.com/pugjs/pug).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is the purpose of this, but you can use Express to start a simple web server that provide the content of your text file. Then, you just need to request this web server from your website page using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const URL_TO_STATIC_TXT = 'https://cdn.rawgit.com/fabe/2a371ce28effb32fa1120f8d25225d37/raw/6d0bfebff1d0b52d72ed5ded4011a0bbff80d679/file.txt';
  
$.ajax({ url: URL_TO_STATIC_TXT })
  .done(data => {
    $('body').text(data);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ A 'good answer' also includes a sentence or two in plain text that explains why you think your solution will work. Please visit SO Help Center and specifically this guideline for more details >>> stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer